# How to use Autohotkey Send Command with Arrays?

Tags: autohotkey

I Want to send keystrokes to HTerm and protocol it via Notepad
Hardcoding all Sends works fine but as soon as i try it with Arrays and Loops nothing works (not even activating the window)

I've tried the following code with all combinations of Light%A_index%, %Light%A_index%, %LightA_index%, Light[A_index] etc.

```
Initialization_Loading_1:

Light := ["F0281", "F0282", "F0283", "F0284", "F0285", "F0286", "F0287", "F0288"] ; Define Array

Return

^2::
Loop % Light.Lenght() ; Send Array to HTerm and Protocol with notepad via Loop
{
IfWinExist, HTerm 0.8.1beta
WinActivate ;
Sender := Light%A_index%
Send, %Sender%
Send, {Enter}
Sleep, 100
IfWinExist, Protokoll.txt - Notepad
WinActivate ;
Send, %Sender%
Send, {Enter}
Sleep, 5000
}
Return
```

The expected result should be typing the commands in Hterm and then in Notepad instead just nothing happens like it doesn't even start the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I used parts of your code for testing (shown at bottom).

The proper way to save an element of your array ("Light") to your variable ("Sender") is like this `Sender := Light[A_Index]`.

There is also a typo in your loop; it should be `Loop , % Light.Length()` (the added comma is optional, but I like it for consistency). I believe the typo may be the reason you're not seeing anything happen.

(This isn't a problem, but may make your code more concise.) There are other ways to use the data. One option is to just send the element of the array directly, with something like `Send , % Light[A_Index]`. Another option may be to use a for-loop instead. Here is an example based on your code:

```
^3::
Light := ["F0281", "F0282", "F0283", "F0284", "F0285", "F0286", "F0287", "F0288"] ; Define Array
For x In Light
{
    Send , % Light[x] . "{enter}"
    Sleep , 100
}
Return
```

Code (working) used for testing:

```
^2::
Light := ["F0281", "F0282", "F0283", "F0284", "F0285", "F0286", "F0287", "F0288"] ; Define Array
Loop , % Light.Length() ; Send Array to HTerm and Protocol with notepad via Loop
{
    Sender := Light[A_Index]
    Send , %Sender%
    Send , {Enter}
    Sleep , 100
}
Return
```